# Google Apps Script drop down menu to display only items that start with A or B or C etc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi is there a way that I can only display items in column A that start with a certain letter via a drop down menu using the Google Apps Script and pulling from a shared Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try something on these lines.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(SHEETNAME); 
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
// Assume column A
var lst = app.createListBox().setId('lst').setName('lst');
for( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
  if(data[i][0].indexOf('A') == 0){
    lst.addItem(data[i][0]);
  }
}
```

Warning: Code not tested